# groovy to list Jenkins jobs with GIT URL used in jobs

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

We need to print Jenkins jobs URLs and GIT URL configured inside these jobs.

For example:

Assume my Jenkins URL is : http://localhost:8080 & my git URL is ssh://git:424

If i run groovy code from Jenkins, It should return:

http://localhost:8080/job_name1  | ssh://git:424/repo_name1 (GIT URL configured in SCM section of  job_name1)

http://localhost:8080/job_name2  | ssh://git:424/repo_name2 (GIT URL configured in SCM section of job_name2)

**I have below code to list jobs** :

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(AbstractProject.class).each {it ->
println it.fullName;
}
```

**and below code to list SCM value**:

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(hudson.model.AbstractProject.class).each {it ->
  scm = it.getScm()
  if(scm instanceof hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM)
  {
    println scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl()
  }
}
println "Done"
```

Above code first returns Jenkins job URLS and then SCM URl but i have to map it manually what SCM belongs to what Jenkins job URL.

Is there a way, i can print Jenkins job URL and its SCM value using groovy.

Appreciate help !

Answer (score 2):

This works with classic jobs and workflow jobs:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob;

def printScm(project, scm){
    if (scm instanceof hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM) {
        scm.getRepositories().each {
            it.getURIs().each {
                println(project + "\t"+ it.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}

Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each {

    project = it.getFullName()
    if (it instanceof AbstractProject){
        printScm(project, it.getScm())
    } else if (it instanceof WorkflowJob) {
        it.getSCMs().each {
            printScm(project, it)
        }
    } else {
        println("project type unknown: " + it)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `WorkflowJob` then the below snippet should work for you.

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each{
scm = it.getTypicalSCM();
project = it.getAbsoluteUrl();
if (scm instanceof hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM) {
scm.getRepositories().each{
    it.getURIs().each{
        println(project.toString() +":"+ it.toString());
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks ! Tried it. Getting following error. Any suggestions:   hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob.getScm() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getSCMs(), getACL(), getACL(), getACL(), getApi(), getName()

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each {
  scm = it.getScm();
  project = it.getAbsoluteUrl();

  if (scm instanceof hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM) {
    scm.getRepositories().each {
      it.getURIs().each {
          println(project.toString() +":"+ it.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
println "done"
```