# Modify git SCM for multiple jobs using groovy script via script console

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy

I have a jenkins master with loads of pipeline (workflow) jobs. I need to change the scm git repo names in all the jobs using a groovy script run via script console.

I came across a bunch of answers for it to work in freestyle jobs. 
Also i came across a solution for pipeline job as this.

[groovy to list Jenkins jobs with GIT URL used in jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53207619/groovy-to-list-jenkins-jobs-with-git-url-used-in-jobs)

It just lists downs the job names and the git repos.

I want to modify the git scm. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Git remote URL is set with the [`src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/UserRemoteConfig.java#UserRemoteConfig`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/92fbfc8292b8f903183f94648a784baab3947f66/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/UserRemoteConfig.java#L45) class, and its [groovy GUI configuration](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/git/UserRemoteConfig/config.groovy).

You can see an example of changing the URL in "[How to change a Git URL in all Jenkins jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27646182/6309)"

```
def newUserRemoteConfigs = oldScm.userRemoteConfigs.collect {
  new UserRemoteConfig(modifyGitUrl(it.url), it.name, it.refspec, it.credentialsId)
}
```

The OP reports a more up-to-date way to update the Git SCM URL, in  "[How to update job config files using the REST API and cURL?](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218353308-How-to-update-job-config-files-using-the-REST-API-and-cURL-)"

> ```
> # Get current config
> curl -X GET http://developer:developer@localhost:8080/job/test/config.xml -o mylocalconfig.xml
>
> # Post updated config
> curl -X POST http://developer:developer@localhost:8080/job/test/config.xml --data-binary "@mymodifiedlocalconfig.xml"
> ```
>
> Obviously, replace:

- `developer:developer` with your username:password
- `localhost:8080` with your Jenkins URL
- `test` with your job name

This is based on the [JENKINS Remote access API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API).

Comment: This doesn't work for the latest git version though. It errors out early at the line  ```def oldScm = it.scm```

Comment: I found a easier way to update it thru api. 
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218353308-How-to-update-job-config-files-using-the-REST-API-and-cURL-
thanks @VonC

Comment: @Jenisha I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.